# insert data into Oracle database using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle

Hi all dear friends i am using node.js for a while and now i am trying to insert data in to Oracle database, but i don't know the way to do it so if anyone know please help me.

## this is my data from request

```
{ 
    '0': '{"startdate":"2020-01-21"}',
    '1': '{"enddate":"2020-01-22"}',
    '2': '{"startdate":"2020-01-21"}',
    '3': '{"startdate":"Microsoft"}',
    '4': '{"startdate":"Active"}',
    '5': '{"startdate":"Test"}' 
   }
```

## and this is my code in node.js

```
exports.postregister = (req, res) => {
conn.connect(function(r, connection) {
    if (r.error_code != '00') {
        res.send(r);
        return;
    } else {
        const sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO REGISTER_LIMIT";
    }
})
}
```

## and this is my table in Oracle

[image]

Comment: Post the rest of your code its hard to tell whats happening, for example where is sqlQuery used?

Comment: Your data has 5 values for `"startdate"` and two of those are dates and 3 of them are not.

Comment: Have a look at this series: https://jsao.io/2018/03/creating-a-rest-api-with-node-js-and-oracle-database/ Part 4 shows an example of taking data from a request and inserting it into the database. https://jsao.io/2018/04/creating-a-rest-api-handling-post-put-and-delete-requests/

Comment: The data appears to be multiple rows, so you should definitely explore `executeMany()` which is much more efficient than inserting each row individually, see the node-oracledb documentation [Batch Statement Execution and Bulk Loading](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#batchexecution).  But if you do use single row INSERTs, make sure you use bind variables.